# How to display images with django-ckeditor?

Tags: python, django, ckeditor

I'm trying to install django-ckeditor and have some trouble. Everything is working fine, 
images are uploading - but they are not displaying. I'm getting 404 error on the file( I'm sure it's there).
Below are screenshots from debug console, permisions on folders and html page.

[image]

Please help me, I'm still learing and to be honest, I don't even know where to look.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone has the same problem I think I found an answer.
Go to : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/ and set media folder. Next set upload inside media folder. It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/) clearly mentioned how to set media url. So the view function will serve the files uploaded by a user during development.

Add this snippet

```
#urls.py

from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # ... the rest of your URLconf goes here ...
) + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```